# sein + zu + Infinitiv + ein Modalverb Konstruktion

Tags: modal-verb, infinitive

Ich habe letztens die folgende Konstruktion gelesen:

> Queen Elizabeth flog sehr gern First Class mit British Airways. Warum **soll** deutschen Regierungsmitgliedern so etwas **nicht zuzumuten sein**?

Ich frage mich jetzt, ob den Muttersprachlern den oben stehenden Satz mit dem betonten wichtigen Teil gut klingt?
Meines Wissens, im z.B. Englischen besteht keine Möglichkeit, sein-zu mit einem Modalverb zu verbinden.

Comment: Ich kann nicht wirklich nachvollziehen, inwieweit das Argument, dass die analoge Konstruktion im im Englischen nicht möglich sein soll, in Bezug auf das Deutsche Gewicht haben soll.

Comment: Noch natürlicher klingen würde für mich _soll ... nicht zumutbar sein_.

Comment: @RHa Mit dem Argument wollte ich auf keinen Fall beleidigen oder die Wichtigkeit/Relevanz der deutschen Sprache unterschätzen. Das Beispiel habe ich nur aus diesem Grund erwähnt, dass bislang Englisch meine einzige gut beherrschte Fremdsprache im germanischen Sprachraum ist und somit es mir als Referenz dient. Vielen Dank für den Kommentar, an dessen Lektion ich mich errinern werde.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Das ist völlig in Ordnung so und klingt auch gut.

Der modale Infinitiv in deinem Beispiel ist *sein*, nicht *zuzumuten*. Dieses *zuzumuten* ist ein Infinitiv der Notwendigkeit oder Unerfüllbarkeit, der als Prädkativ das *sein* ergänzt. Die Funktion ist vergleichbar mit dem Gerundiv, das aber nicht prädikativ verwendet wird – stattdessen steht dann der erweiterte Infinitiv.

Im Englischen gibt es meines Wissens weder ein Gerundiv noch diesen Infinitiv-Ersatz dafür.